# Restrict multiple events in ASP .net & Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a text box with a text change event attached with it;

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtLoadPortCode" MaxLength="8" runat="server" ToolTip="Load     Port Code" CssClass="form-control form-control-Mandatory" OnTextChanged="txtLoadPortCode_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

On text change it fires a server side event to fetch the Name from Database, if Name is missing it shows a Javascript alert triggered from server side.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "OriginPortMissing", "$(function(){alert(\"This combination '" + this.txtLoadPortCode.Text + "' of Country, City & Site is not available in Master table. Please provide a valid Code.\");});", true);
```

I also have a submit button which has a Javascript field validation attached with it;

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSubmitCreateRequest" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-custom btn-Custom-Link" OnClick="btnSubmitCreateRequest_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidateFields();">
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span>Submit Booking</span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

On ValidateFields() function I have written field validation for multiple controls and If any validation fails it shows error message in 'alert' window.

So the scenario is, if User gives some value in text-box and directly clicks on the Submit button then both text change event and Submit button javascript validation gets fired, resulting double alert message at the same time (IE 11 browser).

Is there any way I can restrict Submit button validation event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initally Don't Show the `LinkButton` , set it to `visible="false"`, after the Text Change (I mean in the `Textchanged` event) try to set `LinkButton` the   `visible="true"`

Comment: Nice One. What I did was, instead of hiding it, I made it 'Disabled' initially then after text change I 'Enabled' it.

Answer (score 1):

For this just time limit or just delay the validation by using `setTimeOut`

```
setTimeOut(function(){ put your validation code },10000)
```

Comment: setTimeOut will only delay the alerts, it is not going to prevent it. And the Submit validation alert has a long list so setting a delay for text change alert will not be so user friendly.

Comment: u got two events at the present so this time out will help and extant the time from 10 seconds to 20 seconds i have tried and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

There is provision in Jquery. by using `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` . https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/][1]
Please check this once. This might help you.

Comment: Nice suggestion but in my case both are different events, had it been the same event repeating more than once the I could have used event.stopImmediatePropagation() to restrict the consequent events.